# Regex return file name, remove path and file extension

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have a data.frame that contains a text column of file names. I would like to return the file name without the path or the file extension. Typically, my file names have been numbered, but they don't have to be. For example:

```
df<-data.frame(data=c("a","b"),fileNames=c("C:/a/bb/ccc/NAME1.ext","C:/a/bb/ccc/d D2/name2.ext"))
```

I would like to return the equivalent of

```
df<-data.frame(data=c("a","b"),fileNames=c("NAME","name"))
```

but I cannot figure out the slick regular expression to do this with gsub. For example, I can get rid of the extension with (provided the file name ends with a number):

```
gsub('([0-9]).ext','',df[,"fileNames"])
```

Though I've been trying various patterns (by reading the regex help files and similar solutions on this site), I can't get a regex to return the text between the last "/" and the first ".". Any thoughts or forwards to similar questions are much appreciated!

The best I have gotten is:

```
 gsub('*[[:graph:]_]/|*[[:graph:]_].ext','',df[,"fileNames"])
```

But this 1) doesn't get rid of all the leading path characters and 2) is dependent on a specific file extension.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Perhaps this will get you closer to your solution:

```
library(tools)
basename(file_path_sans_ext(df$fileNames))
# [1] "NAME1" "name2"
```

The `file_path_sans_ext` function is from the "tools" package (which I believe usually comes with R), and that will extract the path up to (but not including) the extension. The `basename` function will then get rid of your path information.

Or, to take from `file_path_sans_ext` and modify it a bit, you can try:

```
sub("(.*\\/)([^.]+)(\\.[[:alnum:]]+$)", "\\2", df$fileNames)
# [1] "NAME1" "name2"
```

Here, I've "captured" all three parts of the "fileNames" variables, so if you wanted just the file paths, you would change `"\\2"` to `"\\1"`, and if you wanted just the file extensions, you would change it to `"\\3"`.

Comment: Interesting approach. For me, this approach is more clear than the regex, which is currently kind of confusing for me. I'll give it a try.

Comment: This worked well, thank you. It makes more sense to me, but that's probably because I need more practice with regex!

Comment: @Docuemada, no problem. As shown, `file_path_sans_ext` is a basic regular expression, as I suspect `basename` is (but haven't checked to verify).

Comment: Yes! the sub("(.*\\/)([^.]+)(\\.[[:alnum:]]+$)", "\\2", df$fileNames) was what I was after. Thanks to you and zipfzapf for the quick and informative responses.

Answer (score 11):

First of all, to get rid of the "leading path", you can use `basename`. To remove the extension, you can use `sub` similar to your description in your question:

```
filenames <- sub("\\.[[:alnum:]]+$", "", basename(as.character(df$fileNames)))
```

Note that you should use `sub` instead of `gsub` here, because the file extension can only occur once for each filename. Also, you should use `\\.` which matches a dot instead of `.` which matches any symbol. Finally, you should append `$` to the pattern to make sure you are removing the extension only if it is at the end of the filename.

**Edit:** the function `file_path_sans_ext` suggested in Ananda Mahto's solution works via `sub("([^.]+)\\.[[:alnum:]]+$", "\\1", x)`, *i.e.* instead of removing the extension as above, the non-extension part of the filename is retained. I can't see any specific advantages or disadvantages of both methods *in the OP's case*.

Comment: You probably need to use an `as.character` around `df$fileNames` if it has been read in as a factor, as in the example data provided.

Comment: Thank you, and thank you for explaining the regexp characters. This works well. For this example, I used ...as.character(df$fileNames).