# Knitr hook to postprocess pdf output?

Tags: r, knitr, rnw

I have `foo.Rnw` file which uses the `extrafont` package for generating figures with text elements that use non-standard font families. After knitr calls pdflatex on my document, I want to run `extrafont::embed_fonts` on the resulting `foo.pdf` file.

I can do this manually, but is there a way to do this from within knitr? (e.g., some knitr package option I can set to automatically call `extrafont::embed_fonts` after it knits my file and runs it through pdflatex)

Comment: How do you knit your document? With the "Compile PDF" button in RStudio?

Comment: Yes. That's how I do it.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28785774/2706569), it is possible to modify the behavior of the "Compile PDF" button in RStudio by setting the YAML option `knit`. This allows to run arbitrary code when hitting the "Knit" button. Note that the code must be formatted as a one-liner and you need to use single quotes for character data (double quotes won't work).

I don't know the `extrafont` package, so here an example that crops the generated PDF. Calling `extrafont::embed_fonts` should work analogously:

````
---
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) { rmarkdown::render(input = inputFile, encoding = encoding); knitr::plot_crop(paste0(basename(tools::file_path_sans_ext(inputFile)), '.pdf')) } )
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
print("Hello world!")
```
````

It's actually pretty simple; the most complicated part is composing the output file name: `(paste0(basename(tools::file_path_sans_ext(inputFile)), '.pdf')` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15073919/2706569)).

Comment: Nice for .Rmd. Is there anything comparable for .Rnw, which doesn't have YAML headers?

Comment: @jgilligan Oh, sorry, I missed the `rnw` tag on your question. At the moment I don't know how to apply this to RNW, but I'll keep it at the back of my head.