# `bookdown`/`rmarkdown`/`knitr`: Hook for execution after output document is finalized?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

My `PDF`-report generation using `bookdown` includes packing of result files into a `zip` archive, into which I (currently manually) integrate the `PDF` document itself as well.

Is there any hook that would enable automating the integration of the finished `PDF`? WOuld require a post-`pdflatex` command by `knitr`, I suppose ...

Comment: How do you currently trigger the knitting? The RStudio button? Is something along the lines of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713618/knitr-hook-to-postprocess-pdf-output helpful?

Comment: That looks interesting indeed ... off investigating.

Comment: You could also just write a function that calls `rmarkdown::render` and follow it by the code to add the PDF into the zip.  If typing the name of the function is too hard, it could be an add-in to RStudio.