# Extract file name from file path

Tags: r, regex, bioinformatics

I got an table "countdata"

```
    /share/Data01/zhangxi/workspace/Bioinformatics_Data/RNA_seq_program/01_4_DESeq2_analysis/B18-N.sorted.bam /share/Data01/zhangxi/workspace/Bioinformatics_Data/RNA_seq_program/01_4_DESeq2_analysis/B18-CA.sorted.bam
ENSG00000223972             0            0
ENSG00000227232           413          196
ENSG00000243485             0            0
ENSG00000237613             0            0
ENSG00000268020             0            0
ENSG00000240361             0            0
```

I did it with R.

```
colnames(countdata) <- gsub("((?:[^/]*/)*)", "", colnames(countdata))
colnames(countdata) <- gsub("\\.[sb]am$", "", colnames(countdata))

#change it into this
                B18-CA.sorted B18-N.sorted
ENSG00000223972             0            0
ENSG00000227232           413          196
ENSG00000243485             0            0
ENSG00000237613             0            0
ENSG00000268020             0            0
ENSG00000240361             0            0
```

How could I change the table in one line?

```
colnames(countdata) <- gsub(Regular_Expression, "", colnames(countdata))
```

Comment: maybe `sub("\\.bam", "", basename(colnames(countdata)))` ?

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073753

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try:

```
sub("\\.bam", "", basename(colnames(countdata)))
```

`basename` permits to retrieve what is after the last `/` in a path.

Comment: the R script came out error. "invalid class "SummarizedExperiment0" object: 'assays' ncol differs from 'colData' nrow"

Comment: @user6903386 what exactly is "SummarizedExperiment0". We are probably missing some elements because with what you posted, it works... please provide more details

Comment: My script is like this:countdata <- countdata[ ,6:ncol(countdata)]
colnames(countdata) <- gsub("((?:[^/]*/)*)", "", colnames(countdata))
colnames(countdata) <- gsub("\\.[sb]am$", "", colnames(countdata))
countdata <- as.matrix(countdata)
head(countdata)
(condition <- factor(c(rep("cancel", 1), rep("normal", 1))))

Comment: @user6903386 try my line of code just after the first step : my line is supposed to replace the `gsub` steps...